# dateutils rrule returns dates that 2 months apart

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-dateutil, rrule

I am new to Python and also `dateutil` module. I am passing the following arguments:

```
disclosure_start_date = resultsDict['fd_disclosure_start_date']
disclosure_end_date = datetime.datetime.now()
disclosure_dates = [dt for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=disclosure_start_date, until=disclosure_end_date)]
```

Here  `disclosure_start_date = 2012-10-31 00:00:00` which converted to datetime is `datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 31, 0, 0)`

End date is as of now.

When I use:

```
disclosure_dates = [dt for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=disclosure_start_date, until=disclosure_end_date)]
```

I get the dates for every other month or 2 months apart. The result is:

```
>>> list(disclosure_dates)
[datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 31, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 31, 0, 0)]
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone please point out the mistake here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue you are coming up against comes from the fact that `datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 31, 0, 0)` is the 31st of the month, and not all months have a 31st. Since the `rrule` module is an implementation of RFC 2445. Per RFC 3.3.10:

> Recurrence rules may generate recurrence instances with an invalid date (e.g., February 30) or nonexistent local time (e.g., 1:30 AM on a day where the local time is moved forward by an hour at 1:00 AM). Such recurrence instances MUST be ignored and MUST NOT be counted as part of the recurrence set.

Since you have a monthly rule that generates the 31st of a month, it will skip all months with 30 or fewer days. You can see [this bug report](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/149) in `dateutil` about this issue.

If you just want the last day of the month, you should use the `bymonthday=-1` argument:

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY
from datetime import datetime

disclosure_start_date = datetime(2012, 10, 31, 0, 0)

rr = rrule(freq=MONTHLY, dtstart=disclosure_start_date, bymonthday=-1)
# >>>rr.between(datetime(2013, 1, 1), datetime(2013, 5, 1))
# [datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 31, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 28, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 31, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 30, 0, 0)]
```

Unfortunately, I don't think there's an RFC-compliant way to generate a simple RRULE that just falls back to the end of the month if-and-only-if it's necessary (e.g. what do you do with January 30th - you need fallback for February, but you don't want to use `bymonthday=-2` because that will give you Feb. 27th, etc).

Alternatively, for a simple monthly rule like this, a better option is probably to just use `relativedelta`, which *does* fall back to the end of the month:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

def disclosure_dates(dtstart, rd, dtend=None):
    ii = 0
    while True:
        cdate = dtstart + ii*rd
        ii += 1

        yield cdate
        if dtend is not None and cdate >= dtend:
            break


dtstart = datetime(2013, 1, 31, 0, 0)
rd = relativedelta(months=1)
rr = disclosure_dates(dtstart, rd, dtend=datetime(2013, 5, 1))

# >>> list(rr)
# [datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 31, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 28, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 31, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 30, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 31, 0, 0)]
```

Note that I specifically used `cdate = dtstart + ii * rd`, you do *not* want to just keep a "running tally", as that will pin to the shortest month the tally has seen:

```
dt_base = datetime(2013, 1, 31)
dt = dt_base
for ii in range(5):
    cdt = dt_base + ii*rd
    print('{} | {}'.format(dt, cdt))
    dt += rd
```

Result:

```
2013-01-31 00:00:00 | 2013-01-31 00:00:00
2013-02-28 00:00:00 | 2013-02-28 00:00:00
2013-03-28 00:00:00 | 2013-03-31 00:00:00
2013-04-28 00:00:00 | 2013-04-30 00:00:00
2013-05-28 00:00:00 | 2013-05-31 00:00:00
```

Comment: FYI, there is [RFC 7529](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7529), which (among other things) extends `RRULE` by a mode that falls back to the last day of a month if a day doesn't exist. The rule `FREQ=MONTHLY;RSCALE=GREGORIAN;SKIP=BACKWARD;BYMONTHDAY=30` would do that. In February this would result in the 28th (or 29th in leap years). Unfortunately there is not much support for this yet.

Comment: @Marten Awesome, didn't know about that. I'll read and implement in dateutil.

Comment: @Paul is there any progress on this issue in dateutil?

Comment: @IvanVirabyan not done yet but some work towards an implementation exists: https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/285 and https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/pull/522

Comment: Close to the end of 2022 now and this problem still exists. Current only alternative is going for a relativedelta solution like the above one.

Answer (score -1):

["datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 3, 0, 0)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVCV9.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).