# Python dateutil - bug with choosing closest day with BYMONTHDAY

Tags: python-dateutil, rrule

I am using python's dateutil module to parse recurring rules in my calendar. A problem arises with the following rrule:

from dateutil.rrule import rrulestr

```
def test():
    rrule = 'FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTHDAY=30;UNTIL=20180331T2359'
    dtstart = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 18, 0)
    dates = list(rrulestr(rrule + ';UNTIL=', dtstart = dtstart ))
```

This results in the following output (missing February):

```
datetime: 2018-01-30 18:00:00
datetime: 2018-03-30 18:00:00
```

Is this a bug in `dateutil` module and how should I fix it? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dateutils rrule returns dates that 2 months apart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328313/dateutils-rrule-returns-dates-that-2-months-apart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my answer [on this equivalent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38555283/467366), this is a deliberate feature of the iCalendar RFC that `dateutil` is implementing, because `dateutil`  implements RFC 2445 and does not support all (or most) of the features of the updated RFC 5545. The relevant section of RFC 2445:

> Recurrence rules may generate recurrence instances with an invalid date (e.g., February 30) or nonexistent local time (e.g., 1:30 AM on a day where the local time is moved forward by an hour at 1:00 AM). Such recurrence instances MUST be ignored and MUST NOT be counted as part of the recurrence set.

February is missing because `2018-02-30` is an invalid date (it's actually the example specified in the RFC).

One thing to note is that [this pull request](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/pull/522) implements the functionality you want, but it is (as of this writing) currently blocked waiting for support of `SKIP` in `BYWEEKNO`. After that is merged, you will be able to modify your RRULE:

```
rrule = ('FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTHDAY=30;UNTIL=20180331T2359;'+
         'SKIP=BACKWARD;RSCALE=GREGORIAN')
```

Until then, your best option may be to use a `BYMONTHDAY=28` and then add a `relativedelta(day=30)` to the result, e.g.:

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def end_of_month(dtstart, until):
    rr = rrule(freq=MONTHLY, interval=1, bymonthday=28,
               dtstart=dtstart, until=until)

    for dt in rr:
        yield dt + relativedelta(day=30)
```

This works because the 28th exists in all months (so the `rrule` will always generate it) and `relativedelta` has the "fall backwards at end of month" behavior that you are looking for. To be 100% safe, you can choose `bymonthday=1` instead, it is equivalent in this case.