# Python dateutils relativedelta incorrect result when starting with 30 day month

Tags: python, python-dateutil, relativedelta

I'm trying to create some date recurrence rules. Based on the issues with `dateutil` noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328313/dateutils-rrule-returns-dates-that-2-months-apart) and [here](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/149) I am trying to use `relativedelta` rather than `rrule`. However, I am encountering a silly problem that is stumping me and which is illustrated with the following minimal example. Consider this:

```
MONTH = relativedelta(months=+1)
print(first_date + MONTH, first_date + 2*MONTH)
```

When `first_date` is the last day in a month with 31 days, such as 05/31/2007, the code yield the correct two dates: June 30th and July 31st.

But, when `first_date` is the last day in a month with 30 days, such as 04/30/2007, the code yields : **May 30th** and June 30th. What it should have given is **May 31st** and June 30th.

Any ideas how I can overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason this doesn't work is because you can't specify you're taking the last day of a month, just the 31st, 30th of 28th. The only reason this works for months with 31 days is simply because that's a special case that must be handled by relativedelta

By adding and subtracting one day, the problem gets resolved:

```py
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

DAY = relativedelta(days=+1)
MONTH = relativedelta(months=+1)

first_date = date(2007, 4, 30) + DAY
print(first_date + MONTH - DAY, first_date + 2*MONTH - DAY)
```

Output:

```
2007-05-31 2007-06-30
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a very interesting solution. Could you explain which this works and/or why such a somewhat indirect approach is needed?

Comment: Done, I updated the answer. Can you accept it you understood?